# update ID automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html

i need a help here. i want to automatically update my iD whenever i submit my  data. let me explain a bit more.

Here is the scenario when i submit a form the id of my page needs to update automatically. for example if i enter id 3 and submit the html form, when i open the form again it must check the Id from database and show the next id.

This means if the last data i  entered has id 3 it then show me id 4 automatically when i refresh the page and want to submit new data
how can i add ID validation query in that code

need your expert advises.. thanks alot!!!

Html

```
<form  action="survey-data-entry.php" name="1st-form" id="form-control"  method="post" >    
<label>Id.</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" 0451211315" name="ID" id="id" required>
```

php

```
if(isset($_POST['ID'])){
         $ID = $_POST['ID'];

    $sql= "INSERT INTO phpstartup (ID, )
    VALUES('$ID') ";

    if(!mysql_query($sql))
    {
        die('caution' . mysql_error());
    }
        echo"1 record added";
}
```

Comment: no one can/will help you unless you show us some code

Comment: @zoubida13 let me edit post

Comment: @zoubida13 now?

Comment: So you insert 3 and then show 4. Meanwhile, another user loads the page. Should he get 4 as well? 5?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sir right now lets suppose only i'm the user of this page so when i loads the page it should show me 4

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the maximum of id + 1 from the query to use it for your next submission.

```
$rslt = mysql_query('SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 as nextId FROM phpstartup');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt);
$nextId = $row['nextId'];
```

Now you can use the variable $nextId in your forms for re submission.